# How to make left outer join over inner join?

Tags: sqlite

I want to make view (catalog_view), which makes inner join between contacts_categories_table and contacts_table (contacts must exist), then left outer join result with categories table (category may not be assigned). As contacts_categories_table has 156 recoreds, I expect catalog_view to containe 176 recoreds too.  However, i get 3003 records in catalog_view. Where did I make error?

catalog_view

```
    CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS catalog_view AS  
    SELECT 
       contacts_table._id AS _id, 
       contacts_table.contact_id, 
       contacts_table.title_lower, 
       contacts_table.note_lower, 
       contacts_table.current_user, 
       contacts_table.saved, 
       contacts_table.partner, 
       contacts_table.title, 
       contacts_table.email, 
       contacts_table.title_short, 
       contacts_table.number, 
       contacts_table.note, 
       contacts_table.categories, 
       categories_table.section_name, 
       contacts_table.contact_id, 
       categories_table.parent_id, 
       categories_table.category_id  
    FROM 
       contacts_categories_table INNER JOIN contacts_table    
    ON(
contacts_categories_table.contact_id = contacts_table.contact_id 
    AND 
contacts_categories_table.current_user = contacts_table.current_user)      
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories_table ON(
contacts_categories_table.category_id = categories_table.category_id 
    AND contacts_categories_table.current_user = categories_table.current_user)
```

`contacts_table` - list of awailible contacts. Has 76 items.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts_table(
   _id integer primary key, 
   title text default '',
   title_lower text default '',
   title_short text default '',
   photo blob, number text default '', 
   note text default '', 
   note_lower text default '', 
   email text, partner int default '0', 
   contact_id int default '0', 
   current_user text default '', 
   categories text default '', 
   saved integer default '0' );
```

`categories_table` - list of awailible categories. Has 1758 items.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories_table(
   _id integer primary key, 
   category_id integer, 
   parent_id integer, 
   name text, 
   section_name text, 
   current_user text, 
   sub_name text);
```

`contacts_categories_table` - is containc recored of which categories were assigned to each contact if any. Has 156 items.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts_categories_table(
      _id integer primary key, 
      contact_id integer, 
      category_id integer, 
      current_user text );
```

Comment: Please provide the EXPLAIN for the above, along with proper CREATE TABLE statements for each of the relevant tables.

Comment: @Strawberry I added shemas for other tables

Comment: Thanks for the progress report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN** in contact_categories_table.
So that you will get all the records from contact_category table.
Hopefully you will get your desired result by this.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS catalog_view AS  
SELECT 
   contacts_table._id AS _id, 
   contacts_table.contact_id, 
   contacts_table.title_lower, 
   contacts_table.note_lower, 
   contacts_table.current_user, 
   contacts_table.saved, 
   contacts_table.partner, 
   contacts_table.title, 
   contacts_table.email, 
   contacts_table.title_short, 
   contacts_table.number, 
   contacts_table.note, 
   contacts_table.categories, 
   categories_table.section_name, 
   contacts_table.contact_id, 
   categories_table.parent_id, 
   categories_table.category_id  
FROM 
   contacts_categories_table 
LEFT JOIN contacts_table    

ON (contacts_categories_table.contact_id = contacts_table.contact_id AND contacts_categories_table.current_user = contacts_table.current_user) 

LEFT JOIN categories_table 

ON(contacts_categories_table.category_id = categories_table.category_id AND contacts_categories_table.current_user = categories_table.current_user)
```

Comment: but your clase will return only contacts with assigned categories, while ill want all contacts present in contacts_categories_table.